# How to serialize a list of SelfDescribingMarshallables to CSV

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-wire

I need to serialize a list of SelfDescribingMarshallables of the same type as CSV output row by row using Chronicle Wire. But `net.openhft.chronicle.wire.WireType#CSV` produces a row for every object field, so it is not a CSV.
Are there any code samples?

Comment: The CSV is conceptually a list of rows/objects. You should be able to dump such a list to the CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WireType#CSV` is currently not in a working condition unfortunately as we haven't had any incentive to support it.
However it's still possible to use low-level CSV marshalling via `BytesMarshallable` (not `SelfDescribingMarshallable`), see example [here](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Wire/blob/master/src/test/java/net/openhft/chronicle/wire/CSVBytesMarshallableTest.java)